# Same code works in Jyputer but MemoryError in Command Line Python

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I defined a function that read 9 CSVs and returns as 9 dataframes.
Those code works well in Jupyter Notebook but when I export the code as `.py` and run it on the command line. I get `MemoryError`

I tried to run the command line as admin but still failed.

Here is the code. Just normal `read_csv`

```
def read_matrixs():
    import pandas as pd
    df1 = pd.read_csv("../Data/1.csv")
    df2 = pd.read_csv('../Data/2.csv', index_col = 0)
    df3 = pd.read_csv("../Data/3.csv", index_col = 0)
    df4 = pd.read_csv('../Data/4.csv', index_col = 0)
    df5 = pd.read_csv('../Data/5.csv', index_col = 0)
    df6 = pd.read_csv('../Data/6.csv', index_col = 0)
    df7 = pd.read_csv('../Data/7.csv', index_col = 0)
    df8 = pd.read_csv('../Data/8.csv', index_col = 0)
    df9 = pd.read_csv('../Data/9.csv', index_col = 0)
    return (df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9)    

df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9 = read_matrixs()
```

Comment: And the functions is....?

Comment: Is it possible that you are using two different versions of Python, i.e. 2 vs 3?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are dealing with code that is too intensive for your computer. I am not familiar with Jupyter Notebook, but it would be really helpful if you could post the code you are trying to run. (Sorry for posting an answer, this should really be a comment. My reputation isn't high enough to comment.)